# How to get data of a refreshing div (Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrap a website which has content (divs) that refreshes every 2 seconds.

My current codes works fine besides I keep on getting `StaleElementReferenceException` because elements keep on refreshing everything 2 seconds.

Below is what I have so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


import time, sys

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', chrome_options=option)
browser.get("example.com")

sports_categories = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.sidebar-wrapper')

for sport in sports_categories:
   if sport.text == 'FOOTBALL':
        sport.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        sub_menus_html = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.category.lvl1.open  div.dropdown')

        print(sub_menus_html)
```

My question is,

- How can I handle this scenario so that i have exact targeted content even though the divs are refreshing in the background

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `click()` is refreshing the elements, you have to gather the current elements in the **DOM**, since the list of elements you gathered before you started looping have become ***STALE***.

Here is an example of how you would loop and keep updating the list object of the elements you are looping on:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', chrome_options=option)
browser.get("example.com")

sports_categories = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.sidebar-wrapper')

# add counter to keep track
counter = 0
for sport in sports_categories:
    #add category refresh here
    current_categories= browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.sidebar-wrapper')
    if current_categories[counter].text == 'FOOTBALL':    
        current_categories[counter].click()
        # I would recommend using something other than sleep to wait for load
        # like webdriverwait conditions combined with Expected Conditions
        time.sleep(2)
        sub_menus_html = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.category.lvl1.open  div.dropdown')
        print(sub_menus_html)
    counter += 1
```

---

Since I do not have access to the website you are working on, I am not sure if this exact code block will work *as is*.

If the length of items in the `div.sidebar-wrapper` changes, or if the items order in that sidebar change, you may have problems.

But still, the logic behind **refresh the list of elements you're looping on** still holds true.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: refreshing divs happens in sub_menus but the main menu is very fine. Can you please update your answer so that i can test it out.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in Python API, but in NodeJS WebDriver API you can `waitForVisible` a particular `XPath` selector and then click it. in your case, the selector could be:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'sidebar-wrapper')][text() = 'FOOTBALL']
```